# EFK stack wit geoip data

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, fluentd, geoip, efk

Hello please can someone advise on following issue:

I have AKS kubernetes cluster and I am using EFK stack to get logs. Fluentd is running in pods.

I have nginx application pod for which I parse log into separate fields.
nginx log:

```
10.244.x.x - - [12/Oct/2020:18:49:09 +0000] "GET /config.json HTTP/1.1" 200 - "https://website.azure.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)"
```

so for the first value (10.244.x.x) I get in kibana: `remote 10.244.x.x`

But I would like to get this ip into geoip format so I can create visualizations in kibana. Please what I need to do to create geoip with EFK ?

I am using fluentd image:  fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset:v1-debian-elasticsearch

Here is my fluen.conf which i insert into fluentd with configmap:

```
# AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE DIRECTLY, USE /templates/conf/fluent.conf.erb

@include "#{ENV['FLUENTD_SYSTEMD_CONF'] || 'systemd'}.conf"
@include "#{ENV['FLUENTD_PROMETHEUS_CONF'] || 'prometheus'}.conf"
@include kubernetes.conf
@include conf.d/*.conf

<filter kubernetes.var.log.containers.skv-ika-q-frontend-*.log>
  @type parser
  key_name log
  reserve_data yes
  format /^(?<remote>[^ ]*) (?<host>[^ ]*) (?<user>[^ ]*) \[(?<time>[^\]]*)\] "(?<method>\S+)(?: +(?<path>[^\"]*?)(?: +\S*)?)?" (?<code>[^ ]*) (?<size>[^ ]*)(?: "(?<referer>[^\"]*)" "(?<agent>[^\"]*)"(?:\s+(?<http_x_forwarded_for>[^ ]+))?)?$/
  time_format %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z
</filter>

<match **>
   @type elasticsearch
   @id out_es
   @log_level info
   include_tag_key true
   host "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST']}"
   port "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT']}"
   path "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PATH']}"
   scheme "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SCHEME'] || 'http'}"
   ssl_verify "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SSL_VERIFY'] || 'true'}"
   ssl_version "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SSL_VERSION'] || 'TLSv1_2'}"
   user "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_USER'] || use_default}"
   password "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD'] || use_default}"
   reload_connections "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_RELOAD_CONNECTIONS'] || 'false'}"
   reconnect_on_error "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_RECONNECT_ON_ERROR'] || 'true'}"
   reload_on_failure "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_RELOAD_ON_FAILURE'] || 'true'}"
   log_es_400_reason "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_LOG_ES_400_REASON'] || 'false'}"
   logstash_prefix "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_LOGSTASH_PREFIX'] || 'logstash'}"
   logstash_dateformat "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_LOGSTASH_DATEFORMAT'] || '%Y.%m.%d'}"
   logstash_format "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_LOGSTASH_FORMAT'] || 'true'}"
   index_name "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_LOGSTASH_INDEX_NAME'] || 'logstash'}"
   type_name "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_LOGSTASH_TYPE_NAME'] || 'fluentd'}"
   include_timestamp "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_INCLUDE_TIMESTAMP'] || 'false'}"
   template_name "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_TEMPLATE_NAME'] || use_nil}"
   template_file "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_TEMPLATE_FILE'] || use_nil}"
   template_overwrite "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_TEMPLATE_OVERWRITE'] || use_default}"
   sniffer_class_name "#{ENV['FLUENT_SNIFFER_CLASS_NAME'] || 'Fluent::Plugin::ElasticsearchSimpleSniffer'}"
   request_timeout "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_REQUEST_TIMEOUT'] || '5s'}"
   suppress_type_name "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SUPPRESS_TYPE_NAME'] || 'true'}"
   enable_ilm "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_ENABLE_ILM'] || 'false'}"
   ilm_policy_id "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_ILM_POLICY_ID'] || use_default}"
   ilm_policy "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_ILM_POLICY'] || use_default}"
   ilm_policy_overwrite "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_ILM_POLICY_OVERWRITE'] || 'false'}"
   <buffer>
     flush_thread_count "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_BUFFER_FLUSH_THREAD_COUNT'] || '8'}"
     flush_interval "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_BUFFER_FLUSH_INTERVAL'] || '5s'}"
     chunk_limit_size "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_BUFFER_CHUNK_LIMIT_SIZE'] || '2M'}"
     queue_limit_length "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_BUFFER_QUEUE_LIMIT_LENGTH'] || '32'}"
     retry_max_interval "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_BUFFER_RETRY_MAX_INTERVAL'] || '30'}"
     retry_forever true
   </buffer>
</match>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the [Fluent GeoIP plugin](https://github.com/y-ken/fluent-plugin-geoip#readme) for that purpose and the Maxmind GeoIP database.

> Fluentd Filter plugin to add information about geographical location
> of IP addresses with Maxmind GeoIP databases.

[Here](https://banzaicloud.com/blog/logging-operator-efk/) is a great article about using EFK with GeoIP. Along with github examples should help you get started. Also last section of [this](https://medium.com/swlh/fluentd-splitting-logs-2a778cd6bdfa) article have also an example how the filter can be configured.